# Copying contents from one array to another in c

Tags: c, arrays

Here is an outline of what my program is suppose to do so far.

While there are more words in `inputLine`:

- take next word from the `inputLine`
- if next word fits in the `inputline2`

  - add the nextword to `inputline2` (doesn't work and maybe not needed)
  - add the `inputline2` to `outputBuffer` (doesn't work)
  - format `outputBuffer`

Otherwise:

- write the `outputBuffer` to the output file
- empty out the `outputBuffer` (put \0 in position 0)

No matter what I try though, the `outputline2` and/or `outputBuffer` never copy the contents of the `inputline` properly. The only reason I have `inputline2` is because I was originally using `fgets` and putting the contents from a line in a text file into `inputline`. However, since my array length is suppose to be 40, it would always cut some of the words in the original line in half. If this could be avoided somehow I wouldn't even need `inputline2`. Either way, in both cases, the contents from word (which is just a single word from the original `inputline`) won't ever copy properly.

```
void format(FILE *ipf, FILE *outf)
{
    char inputline[80];
    char outputBuffer[MaxOutputLine];
    char word[MaxOutputLine];

    while(fgets(inputline, 80, ipf) != NULL)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        int i;
        int j = 0;
        char inputline2[MaxOutputLine] = {'\0'};

        while(pos != -1)
        {
            i=0;
            pos = nextword(inputline, word, pos);

            if(strlen(word) <= (40 - strlen(inputline2)))
            {
                while(i < strlen(word))
                {
                    inputline2[j] = word[i];
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
                j++;
                printf("%s", inputline2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `nextword` do?

Comment: If I understood properly you want to split input line into separate words. There is another simple and effective method: for each word use eg. index() or memchr() to find delimiter (space), change delimiter to \0, output the word and jump into next word position (first character after \0).

Comment: nextword takes a word beginning from pos and puts it in word and returns the pos of the beginning of the next word.

Comment: I'm trying to get the words from inputline[80] and put them into inputline2[40]. Then put the words from inputline2 and put them into the outputBuffer[40]. Right and left justify the words. Then put it into the output file.

Comment: assuming the `MaxOutputLine` is a #define'd value by convention, #define'd names are all upper case, separated by underscores I.E. `MAX_OUTPUT_LINE`.   However, that name is not really informative.  Suggest: `MAX_OUTPUT_LINE_LEN`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers (40, 80).  'magic' numbers make code unnecessarily difficult to understand and a real headache to maintain.  Suggest using #define with meaningful names and use those meaningful names through out the code

Comment: the loop that is checking the value of 'pos' is continuing to execute the code after getting a returned value of -1 from the function `nextword()`  Suggest making the loop `while(1)` and checking the returned value from nextword() immediately after calling nextword() and calling `break;` if the returned value is -1

Answer (score 0):

As I can't format a code in comment I send it as answer.
First, I guess your nextword() is similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int nextword(char *inputline, char *word, int pos)
{
    char *ptr;
    int len;

    ptr = strchr(&inputline[pos], ' ');
    len = ptr ? ptr - &inputline[pos] : strlen(&inputline[pos]);
    strncpy(word, &inputline[pos], len);
    word[len] = 0;
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return -1;
    return pos + len + 1;
}
```

To make clear:

```
#define MaxOutputLine 40
```

In format() you have missed the line:

```
    if(strlen(word) <= (40 - strlen(inputline2)))
    {
        while(i < strlen(word))
        {
            inputline2[j] = word[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        inputline2[j] = ' ';/*missed, otherwise undefined, eg. \0 */
        j++;
        printf("%s", inputline2);
    }
```

Some compilers have problem with long buffers on stack. You can try to add "static" before char buf[] in format().

In nextword() you have the mistake:

```
  if(pos1 == '\n' || pos1 == '\0')
    {
      return -1;
    }
```

instead of

```
if(inputline[pos1] == '\n' || inputline[pos1] == '\0')
{
  word[pos2]='\0';
  return -1;
}
```

In my opinion nextword() could be simplified to something like that:

```
int nextword(char *inputline, char *word, int pos1)
{
  int pos2 = 0;

      while(inputline[pos1] != ' ' && inputline[pos1] != '\n' && inputline[pos1] != '\0')
        {
          word[pos2] = inputline[pos1];
          pos1++;
          pos2++;
        }
      word[pos2]='\0';
      if(inputline[pos1] == '\n' || inputline[pos1] == '\0')
        {
          return -1;
        }

   return pos1 + 1;
}
```

Comment: Different:

`
int nextword(char *inputline, char *word, int pos1) 
{
  int pos2 = 0;

  if(inputline[pos1] == '\0')
    {
      return -1;
    }

  if(inputline[pos1] == ' ')
    {

      while(inputline[pos1] == ' ')
        {
          pos1++;
        }
    }
  else
    {
      while(inputline[pos1] != ' ' && inputline[pos1] != '\n' && inputline[pos1] != '\0')
        {
          word[pos2] = inputline[pos1];
          pos1++;
          pos2++;
        }
      if(pos1 == '\n' || pos1 == '\0')
        {
          return -1;
        }
      pos1++;
    }
  word[pos2]='\0';

   return pos1;
}
`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? As long as I read a text file, format it, then put it into an output file I'm good. I just thought it would be easier to format using two arrays: inputline2 and outputBuffer.

Comment: Format it in stackoverflow for others (resend it as answer). It is difficult to read unformatted code directly.

Comment: My output is much better but still messed up.

My text file reads:
Since it began to escape from AT&T's Bell Laboratories in
the early 1970's, the success of the UNIX
operating system has led to many different
versions: recipients of the (at that time free) UNIX system
code all began developing their own different
versions in their own,
different, ways for use and sale. Universities, research
institutes, government bodies and computer
companies all began using the powerful UNIX system to develop
many of the technologies which
today are part of a UNIX system.

Comment: My output comes out as:

Since it began to escape from AT&T's the early 1970's, the success of the operating system has led to many versions: recipients of the (at that code all began developing their own versions in their different, ways for use and sale. institutes, government bodies and companies all began using the powerful many of the technologies today are part of a UNIX system.

Answer (score 0):

```
int nextword(char *inputline, char *word, int pos1)   //takes a word beginning from pos and puts it in word and re\
turns the new position of beginning of the next word
{
  int pos2 = 0;

  if(inputline[pos1] == '\0')
    {
      return -1;
    }

  if(inputline[pos1] == ' ')
    {

      while(inputline[pos1] == ' ')
        {
          pos1++;
        }
    }
  else
    {
      while(inputline[pos1] != ' ' && inputline[pos1] != '\n' && inputline[pos1] != '\0')
        {
          word[pos2] = inputline[pos1];
          pos1++;
          pos2++;
        }
      if(pos1 == '\n' || pos1 == '\0')
        {
          return -1;
        }
      pos1++;
    }
  word[pos2]='\0';

   return pos1;
}
```